# Embed a Powerpoint in a Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to embed a PowerPoint slide show in an HTML Angular JS page using just the standard tags etc?

I am looking for a way to show the slide show using only standard stuff. I realize I could use google docs or flash or something, but I'd rather have a simple implementation.

Does the web just not know how to process a PowerPoint presentation?

Comment: I don't think HTML can support power point. At the very least you will need some javascript library to do the presentation.

Comment: which javascript library you recommend